# How to tell React-Redux view when action has completed?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Sorry for the possibly unclear subject line here.

My "add review" view fires off a start action.
The reducer responds to the start action by setting `isLoading` to true, which causes the view to show that it's loading.
When my action completes, both success and failure set `isLoading` to false in the reducer, and the activity indicator disappears.

In the case of failure I can write an error to the reducer and I can have the error rendered in my view when an error exists in the reducer, and I can clear the error in the reducer the next time the start action fires.

So I can inform my view of an error, but how do inform my view of success, and replace the review for with the review list?

All the solutions I can think of sound clunky and wrong:

- A `newReview` property in the reducer, whereby my view renders the review list if `newReview` is truthy, and then fires off a "clear new review action"?
- Somehow storing the `attemptedReview` and adding a `showList` logic that entails checking whether the `attemptedReview` exists in the current product's reviews? Where that `showList` logic also, more simply, includes the state of whether the user has *chosen* to show the list or show the form?

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to simulate this kind of behavior by creating a new `resetAction` that *resets* the redux store, and a new variable on the reducer state called `isSuccess`.

This way, when your initial action succeeds, you set the `isSuccess` to true, then you catch the `isSuccess` on your respective Component and handle the logic you want (Redirects or state changes) and finally call the `resetAction` so the redux store comes back to normal.

I guess it's kinda clunky and not elegant but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If your using React 16.8 hooks should be a good option

[Use effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) = componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined

**Example**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import AppInitActions from './store/actions/awesomeactions';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => store.dispatch(AppInitActions.handleCoolAction()), []);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
   <!....<Myactions />....>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

For a given state structure:

```
{
 "PRODUCT-1": {
   id: "PRODUCT-1",
   reviews: [],
 }
}
```

**1. Dispatch `addReviewSuccess` after posting the review**

```
postSomething('SOME_API_ENDPOINT', { id, newReview })
  .then(() => addReviewSuccess(id, newReview));

addReviewSuccess = (id, newReview) => {
  const payload = {
    id,
    newReview,
  };

  dispatch(addReviewSuccess(payload));
}
```

**2. Listen for `ADD_REVIEW_SUCCESS` in Reducer**

The system can listen for `ADD_REVIEW_SUCCESS` action to add the `review` to the list of `reviews` for that specific `product`.

```
// Action
{
  type: 'ADD_REVIEW_SUCCESS',
  payload: {
    id: "PRODUCT-1",
    newReview: {
      message: 'some review',
    }
  }
}

// Reducer
case 'ADD_REVIEW_SUCCESS':
  const newReview = payload.newReview;
  const product = state.products[payload.id];

  return {
    ...state.products,
    [product.id]: {
      ...state.products[product.id],
      reviews: [
        ...state.products[product.id].reviews,
        newReview
      ]
    }
  };
```

**3. Re-render component every `ADD_REVIEW_SUCCESS`**

Then your component will re-render every time the product has new reviews.
Take note of the `key` prop as this is very helpful for React's [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

```
// Product
mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { products } = this.state;

  return {
    products,
  }
}

const ProductList = (products) => (
  <Products>
  { Object.values(products).map((product) => (
    <Product key={product.id}>
      <Reviews reviews={product.reviews} />
    </Products>
  )}
);

// Reviews
const Reviews = (reviews) => (
  { reviews.map((review) => (
    <Review>{review.message}</Review>
  )}
)
```

Comment: If it were simply a matter of updating the review list this would work, since "updating the list" is really just "rendering the current list". However I also need to hide the review form component, which is not really tied to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a unique identifier to the data in the reducer.
That way the view will always update when the action is triggered, even if the result is unchanged.

Timestamps are pretty good, because you can use that value for other things (e.g. "last updated x time ago"), but you need to be careful about the time source or you could have some weird bugs.
Basically you need a monotonically increasing value, so for timestamps that would mean using `performance.now()`.
You can also simply use an integer starting at 0 for the first action, and increment it for each new action.

The downside of course, is that if you display this data somewhere else, it will also re-render every time even when not needed. That means you will need to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` in this component to prevent this.